# Running the command sudo -u postgres createuser -d -R -S $USER I get the message could not change directory to "/home/odoo": Access denied in Ubuntu22

Tags: permissions, 22.04, postgresql

I am trying to install postgresql on Ubuntu 22.04 and to do so I run the following command

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-client
```

followed by that (in the next prompt) I execute the following

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -d -R -S $USER
```

and I get the following message in the terminal

**could not change directory to "/home/odoo": Access denied**

I have tried the following command as well

```
sudo su -c "createuser -s $USER" postgres
```

and the same access denied message appears. **It should be noted that the user is created correctly**.

Should that be the correct operation?

How can I solve it?

What causes that message?

Should I ignore the message?

**Addit:**

The main reason for my question was more out of curiosity and desire to learn than because I was simply getting to the end of what I was trying to do when installing postgresql. Let me explain better, I was trying to install postgresql as part of a process to set up a development environment.

When executing the command described in the question I got the **access denied message**, but I commented in the question, the user was created correctly and continued with the process and reached the end without problems.

Given this explanation, I want to comment that I tried the option mentioned in the second comment by @Raffa and it stopped showing the access denied message and everything else remained OK. The command is as follows:

```
sudo --login -u postgres createuser -d -R -S $USER
```

At this point I wonder if it is because when installing Ubuntu I set it to log in automatically, that is, without asking me for a password. I will install again without setting this option and try again. I'll come back and post the result.

I want to thank the community for being willing to share their knowledge.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229084/65304) suggests the error arises because the postgres process doesn't have permission to set its working directory to the current directory. It's not clear to me whether it may be ignored or needs to be fixed.

Comment: Your command might need the target user's login environment ... so try with `sudo --login -u postgres createuser -d -R -S $USER` or with `sudo su --login postgres -c "createuser -s $USER"`

Comment: ... You might want to specify the actual username instead of `$USER` though in that case. although it should expand before passing it to the target shell if using double quotes ... But, might be passed as a parameter if single quoted ... So, be cautious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a command as another user with `sudo -u ...` or a command string with `su username -c "..."`, you need to keep in mind that the target user's expected login environment (as if that user actually logged in) is not necessarily fully set up and made available to that command unless the option `--login` is specified.

Your command seems to include a procedure involving changing directory to the target user's home (in that case, the invoking user i.e. `postgres`), but instead and because whatever environment variable or environment reliant procedure it calls/invokes translates to your current running user instead i.e. `odoo`, it gets denied access and hence the error message:

> `could not change directory to "/home/odoo": Access denied`

Therefore, you will need to invoke the target user as a login user with like so:

```
sudo --login -u postgres createuser -d -R -S $USER
```

or like so:

```
sudo su --login postgres -c "createuser -s $USER"
```

Please see this demonstration:

```
$ whoami
ubuntu
$
$
$ echo ~
/home/ubuntu
$
$
$ sudo -u test pwd
/home/ubuntu
$
$
$ sudo --login -u test pwd
/home/test
$
$
$ sudo su test -c "pwd"
/home/ubuntu
$
$
$ sudo su --login test -c "pwd"
/home/test
```

**Notice** that when passing a parameter/variable in a command string e.g. `... -c "...$var"`, that parameter will be expanded to its value on the command line under your current running user before it gets passed to the target user's environment if the command string is double quoted `"...$var"` like for example:

```
$ whoami
ubuntu
$
$
$ sudo su test -c "echo $USER"
ubuntu
```

and will be passed as is (without expansion) and might expand later if single quoted `'...$var'`like:

```
$ whoami
ubuntu
$
$
~$ sudo su test -c 'echo $USER'
test
```

also notice the combined usage of `sudo su ...` is rarely needed so using either `sudo -u ...` or `su user ...` is more common.